# trigger !! opportunity stage to "CLosed won" -->Automatic mail to the emailaddress specified in opportunitycontactrole

Tags: trigger

Requirement on trigger -- my requirement is if we change the opportunity stage  to "CLosed won" , 
 based on email address present in  Contact role in  opportunity line item  we need to send an automatic reply email (Thanks for the purchase etc )to that email address  .

Comment: hi benny , trigger EmailOpl on Opportunity (after update) 
{
set<id> optyId = new set<id>();

for(Opportunity opp :trigger.new)
 {
 optyId.add(opp.id);
 //system.debug ();
 }

//query on template object
EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where name=:'Thank you for your order'];

list<OpportunityContactRole> OppCtRole = [SELECT  OpportunityId , role  FROM OpportunityContactRole where OpportunityId =:optyId  ];

//for(OpportunityContactRole ocs : trigger.new )
//{
//optyId.add(ocs.OpportunityId);
//}



}

Comment: i have wrote a few code in my org ... now i am in doubt how to fetch the contactemail id from opportunitycontactrole

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a 'do my homework' type question. I won't write your trigger for you, but I can point you in the right direction.

You have 3 main tasks here:

- Determine if an Opportunity has changed to Closed - Won
- Get a Contact (and their email address)
- Build and send an email

The first bit is almost too basic to go into detail about. Loop over `Trigger.new`, and compare `StageName` against both your target `StageName` and the `StageName` of the corresponding record in `Trigger.oldMap`.

Second is getting the email address of your target contact. This information won't be available in the trigger context variables, so you'll need to query for it.

One way or another, you'll be querying `OpportunityContactRole`, which is a junction object between `Opportunity` and `Contact`. The email address, however, resides on the `Contact`, so you'll need to pull that in using a child-parent relationship query (`Contact.Email`). In the end, one possible query you could use is this:

```
[SELECT OpportunityId, ContactId, IsPrimary, Role, Contact.Email FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE OpportunityId IN :Trigger.newMap.keyset()];
```

If you use the above query, I'd recommend looping over the results and placing them in a `Map<Id, List<OpportunityContactRole>>` where the key of the map is the `OpportunityId`. That way, you don't need to go fishing through the entire result set of the query for each opp. To populate that map, you'll need a basic if-else.

```
if(oppsToContactRoles.containsKey(contactRole.OpportunityId)){
    oppsToContactRoles.get(contactRole.OpportunityId).add(contactRole));
} else {
    oppsToContactRoles.put(contactRole.OpportunityId, new List<OpportunityContactRole>{contactRole});
}
```

Finally, sending emails is handled by classes in the `Messaging` namespace, namely the `Messaging` and `SingleEmailMessage` classes. [Salesforce has a pretty good explanation and example of using these classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_forcecom_email_outbound.htm).

That should give you all the tools you need to write your trigger.

Comment: Just a note, this can probably be done with some combination of `Workflow` / `ProcessBuilder`. It might take more than one flow, but also in general I prefer a clicks not code approach. Still, +1 for an appropriate answer to a weak question.

Comment: I thought about accomplishing this through workflow as I was writing my answer, but I decided against it because I've never had much luck trying to set the recipient(s) of the email alert. Took another look at it, and what do you know? Related contacts for an Opportunity are easily accessible!

Comment: hi Derek , actually i am new to coding ,sorry for that ... thanks alot for your help , i will try to write my code in my org , with the above suggestions , thanks for guiding